# Move all figures to a specific monitor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if there is any known way of moving MATLAB figures to a specific monitor.

I have the following snippet that helps me bring all figures to the front (I got it from Mathworks [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1USVE3/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1USVE3)):

```
%% Bring all figures to front
all_figure_handles = findall(0, 'type', 'figure');
for iCount = length(all_figure_handles):-1:1
   figure(all_figure_handles(iCount))
end
```

And I was wondering if I could ask MATLAB to move all figures to another screen in a similar fashion (i.e. using the handles from `all_figure_handles`).

Alternatively, if MATLAB is not aware of the monitor partitioning, how could I move all figures to, say, the right half of the total screen space? (in my case, the right half  should be the monitor on the right).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Matlab figure documentation:

> Specifying Figure Size and Screen Location
>
> To create a figure window that is one quarter the size of your screen and is positioned in the upper left corner, use the root object's ScreenSize property to determine the size. ScreenSize is a four-element vector: [left, bottom, width, height]:
>
> `scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
>   figure('Position',[1 scrsz(4)/2 scrsz(3)/2 scrsz(4)/2])`
>
> To position the full figure window including the menu bar, title bar, tool bars, and outer edges, use the OuterPosition property in the same manner.

Like this:

`set (gcf(), 'outerposition', [25 500, 560, 470])`

And furthermore, in the documentation for Root Properties:

> MonitorPositions
>
> [x y width height;x y width height]
>
> Width and height of primary and secondary monitors, in pixels. Contains the width and height of each monitor connnected to your computer. The x and y values for the primary monitor are 0, 0 and the width and height of the monitor are specified in pixels.
>
> The secondary monitor position is specified as:
>   x = primary monitor width + 1
>   y = primary monitor height
>
> Querying the value of the figure MonitorPositions on a multiheaded system returns the position for each monitor on a separate line.
>   v = get(0,'MonitorPositions')
>   v = 
>    x y width height % Primary monitor
>    x y width height % Secondary monitor
>
> The value of the ScreenSize property is inconsistent when using multiple monitors. If you want specific and consistent values, use the MonitorPositions property.

Comment: Look out for the location and size of the Windows task-bar. If I recall correctly, it can affect the origin of the coordinate system.

Comment: I just tried 'get(0, 'monitorpositions') on my iMac, and it excluded the menur bar height. I assume it would work similarly on Windows.

Comment: Note also that, at least on the Mac, having the "primary" monitor on the left (vs on the right) of the two-monitor setup will also complicate things, and the above documentation will probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: You must have your primary monitor on the left to use this
>
> v = get(0,'MonitorPositions') otherwise you get bad coordinates.
>
> Example
>
> primary monitor on the right =  Monitor 2 + Monitor 1

type on command window

```
get(0,'MonitorPositions')

ans =

       1           1        1920        1080
   -1919           1           0        1080
```

> bad coordinates on the second row. You don't have to get negative or zero coordinates
>
> Now, 
>   primary monitor on the left = Monitor 1 + Monitor 2

```
get(0,'MonitorPositions')

ans =

1921           1        3840        1080

1           1        1920        1080
```

> To change the primary monitor on windows 8
>
> Right click desktop, screen-resolution, select-monitor,make this monitor the primary monitor.